# Not able to generate executable using makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to clean and make the executable using makefile, but I get the following error when I try to do the same.

Makefile:70: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.

Can someone please help me figure out the error?

Thanks and regards,

Rohit

Comment: I get this error whenever is try to execute any make command like make clean or make sqllibv1 etc. I there any way to validate the makefile for syntactical errors?

Comment: please post your makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make is telling you about the syntax errors; that's the validation.

Every recipe line in a makefile must start with a hard TAB character as the first character in that line.  You cannot use spaces for indentation of recipe lines.